# getting SSLCACertificateError in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a following single line code in rails:

```
Curl::Easy.new("https://www.uts.edu.au/" ).perform
```

Running this is giving following error:

```
Curl::Err::SSLCACertificateError: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Can anyone please suggest how to fix it ?

For further help:

```
 curl -v https://www.uts.edu.au/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x16a3a40
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x16a3a40) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.uts.edu.au port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 54.79.20.73...
* Connected to www.uts.edu.au (54.79.20.73) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Curl is failing to use trusted CAs. By any chance, are you running this inside a Docker Container without CAs?

Please provide the output of `curl -v https://www.uts.edu.au/`

**Update:**
It seems there is a problem with the Chain of Certificates for the host you are making requests.

> The certificate might lack necessary meta-data or its certificate
>   authority might be malfunctioning

https://whatsmychaincert.com/generate?host=www.uts.edu.au

Comment: Thanks. Added. Nope we not running it inside Docker container.

Comment: You have on the output "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" What Operating System are you using?

Comment: Update: found an issue with the chain provided by www.uts.edu.au

Comment: Thanks a lot, Super helpful!